# Where can I find data pairs to practice implementing linear regression?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, linear-regression

I've recently started learning machine learning algorithms. I've written a program in python from scratch to implement linear regression but I need some data pairs to use.

Answer (score 1):

There are many dataset at internet to use,

have a look here, you can find many real datasets: [uci](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use scikit learn, It has some good in build dataset. You can refer this [document.](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/datasets/plot_iris_dataset.html)